# Help to understand why solution to the equation is as such? $\lambda(y_{1},\ y_{2},...,y_{n}) \ + \ (\lambda-1)(z_{1},\ z_{2},...,z_{n}) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider 2 $n$-tuples
$(y_{1},\ y_{2},...,y_{n})$
$(z_{1},\ z_{2},...,z_{n})$
solving the following system of m linear equations in $n$ variables $x_{1},...,x_{n}$
$$a_{11}x_{1}\ +\ ... \ +\ a_{1n}x_{n}\ =\ b_{1}$$
$$a_{m1}x_{1}\ +\ ... \ +\ a_{mn}x_{n}\ =\ b_{m}$$
For every scalar $\lambda$ $\in$ $\mathbb R$, the following linear combinations are also solutions:

$$\lambda(y_{1},\ y_{2},...,y_{n}) \ + \ (\lambda-1)(z_{1},\ z_{2},...,z_{n})  $$

Why is the solution as such? Why specifically $\lambda$ and $(\lambda - 1)$?

Answer (score 0):

If we take $x=\lambda y+\gamma z$, we get
\begin{align*}
a_{i1} x_1+\dots + a_{in} x_n&=a_{i1}(\lambda y_1+\gamma z_1) + \dots + a_{in}(\lambda y_n+\gamma z_n) \\
&= \lambda (a_{i1} y_1 + \dots + a_{in} y_n) + \gamma (a_{i1} z_1 + \dots + a_{in} z_n)\\
&= \lambda b_i + \gamma b_i\\
&= (\lambda + \gamma) b_i
\end{align*}

Therefore the equations are satisfied if $\lambda + \gamma = 1$ or $b_i=0$, so as long as one of the $b_i$ is not null, you want $\gamma=1-\lambda$ and not $\gamma=\lambda-1$ which would give $\lambda + \gamma = 2\lambda - 1\neq 1$ and therefore works only for $\lambda=1$.

Comment: @P
I'm sorry I don't really follow the math as I've just started to learn Linear Algebra. Am I correct in understanding that by replacing $x$ with $x=\lambda y+\gamma z$, it means that it is trying to prove that as long as there is more than 1 solution to a linear equation, there are infinite solutions? Also, how can you equate the $a_{i1}y_{1} + ... + a_{in}y_{n} = b_{i}$?

Comment: for your first question yes, for the second, this is because $y$ is a solution to the system of equation that you mentionned.

Comment: @P
So if I multiply the y tuple and the z tuple together with the matrix of $A_{mn} = a_{11} + ... + a_{mn}$, they will give me $b_{i}$ because they are solutions of the equation right? Also, we use λ and λ−1 so that we can equate $a_{i1}x_{1} + ... + a_{in}x_{n}$ to $b_{i}$ right? Sorry, the math really is quite foreign to me haha.

Comment: Yes, but the matrix is $A$ such that element $A_{ij}=a_{ij}$. What I prove is that $\lambda$ and $\lambda-1$ don't work together, but $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ do.

Comment: @P
I'm so sorry. I just realized I have been copying the text over wrongly onto the question and comments. The line should instead read $\lambda(y_{1},\ y_{2},...,y_{n}) \ + \ (\lambda-1)(z_{1},\ z_{2},...,z_{n})  $ as you mentioned. I'm confused as to why to choose $1 - \lambda$. I understand from your working that we want to equate the coeff of $b_{i}$ to 1 so that it will equal the original solution, but how do we know specifically the value $1-\lambda$? Sorry for the confusion.